# Knockout List Item Animation

Tags: jquery-ui, animation, knockout.js

I've been working with Knockout.js for some time now but only recently I've started to integrate jqueryUI animations for the sake of a better user experience.  I'm seeing some issues trying to use the animation bindings on the tr elements inside a table tag.  When I use the "visible" binding to hide and show each element it works just fine but when I attempt to animate the showing hiding of each element it only seems to apply to the first row in the table.  I've attempted this using various methods.  I've attempted using the knockout foreach template 'afterAdd' option as described here:

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html#note_5_postprocessing_or_animating_the_generated_dom_elements

I've also created a custom binding and attempted to use that on each of the table row items with the same results.

Lastly I attempted to use the plugin found here:

http://www.codecoding.com/knockout-plugin-visibility-bindings-with-jqueryui-effects/

And again, it only appears to work on the first element of the table.  Now before attempting to rewrite my HTML to use divs and spans rather than the tables I wanted to see if anybody else has seen these sorts of issues with knockout in the past.  The relevant chunk of HTML is this:

```
<table class="tab_table table_a">
    <tbody data-bind="foreach:featuredMenuItems,visible:showFeatured">                                              
        <tr data-bind="fadeVisible:readyToShow, click:function(){$root.showProductOptions($data);}">            
            <td class="td_large" data-bind="css:{td_select:itemInCart};"><span class="inCart_delete" data-bind="css:{display_IB:itemInCart},click:removeFromCart,clickBubble:false"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></span><span data-bind="text:name"></span></td>
            <td class="td_last" data-bind="css:{td_select:itemInCart},text:lineItemCost"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I would paste the ViewModel code in here as well but it is a rather large view model and the relevant part to this is just a simple "readyToShow" observable set to either true or false.  Whenever this table is being shown the "readyToShow" values of each of the objects in the observableArray containing the table items is being set to true over time using a timeout so as to show a cascading effect when the table is shown.

I would really appreciate any help you guys could provide.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure which browser you are using, but IE doesn't like doing some things with table rows. Putting the same binding on the columns instead should work. I made an example jsfiddle with a `fadeVisible` binding (since that was what you were using) which you can find at http://jsfiddle.net/ttwLamt4/. It shows putting the `fadeVisible` binding on the row (works in FF and Chrome, not IE) and on the cells (works in all three). Perhaps you should make a `fadeChildrenVisible` binding instead, which would fade the children of the element it is applied to and you could set it on the row?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. My situation is more like this example jsfiddle.net/robando/ufep5qf5 where there is a computed being driven off of an observable array. For some reason I can get it to work just fine in JSFiddle but in my development environment it still appears as though the jquery matches only the first element and ignores the others. The top element seems to be the matched element every time that one of the other elements is set to readyToShow

Comment: If you're not able to reproduce the issue in a jsfiddle it's very hard for someone else, with less knowledge about your code to help you. Also, if you get it working in the fiddle, perhaps the problem lies in the rest of your code (or different library versions between your code and the fiddle)?